# 404 error handling for a non-existing dynamic URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers, http-status-code-404

Right now I got my .htaccess setup correctly:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Whenever I access a non-existing page like mysite.com/g.php it gets redirected to the 404.php, header shows the 404 status.

Whenever somebody tries to access a story that doesn't exist, like mysite.com/story/123456 the 404 status is in the header, but no redirection to the 404 page.

I use this code whenever a story does not exist:

```
if ($result == 0) { header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); exit();}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to redirect to that error page by means of a location header? You already have that page setup as `ErrorDocument`.

Comment: Well, it was an experiment. I do expect the .htaccess to do that part.

Comment: I removed it from the question, too puzzling

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you are trying to do!

Comment: This may depend on what `$result` is. Have you tried `if ($result == FALSE)` or `NULL`? Question's a tad unclear for me.

Comment: The result part works. I just want to correctly have an 404 page when a dynamic URL has no results in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got a solution for the issue.

This code will give a 404 error and then I include the 404-page to show a page:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); include '404include.php'; exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your error document the full path:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/404.php
```

Comment: This is how I have it on production servers, and will work no matter where the 404 happens, needs to be the canonical URL for that page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to set a http response status:

```
<?php
// ...
if ($result == 0) { 
    http_response_code(404);
    exit();
}
```

Together with a `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` in your http servers host configuration (or, if really necessary, in a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess`)) that should do what you intend.

The corresponding documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: Function name is `http_response_code` with underscores

Comment: @VeeK Whoops, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed in the answer.